# Massive performance difference between RAW SQL into SQL DB and SQL Via DynaAccess

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, database, odbc

this may be a complete stab in the dark due to my circumstances, but I have no were else to turn!

I work in a production environment and we have a tailored program to track all product information throughout the day. This goes through the program and goes into an SQL database with lots of tables.

SO, to get data out of the database we have two options, one is to use raw SQL in the tailor made program, a simple select query runs instantly...

The query is like this -

```
Select * from table where DATE_STAMP > 212257195260000000
```

The other option is to use microsoft query and ODBC with DynaAccess to query the database. For the same query it takes at least 30 seconds longer.

Since recently developing a .NET application in C# to sync data from the production database into a replicated mysql database this has increasingly became more of a problem. I am currently syncing around 20 tables from the database and this can take up to 10 minutes to get around 10-15 rows of data as the loop goes round on a 15 seconds basis.

Once again, the querys that are used in the .NET application are exactly the same as what I would use in the tailored program, and again have a massive difference in time it takes to return the data.

And its probably worth mentioning that the DATE_STAMP field has an index on it.

Like I said, this is a stab in the dark, but hopefully someone could give me a bit of advice.

If any more information is needed, please ask!

Comment: what is DynaAccess? if that's the bottleneck then don't use it...

Comment: Thanks for the sarcastic comment. Obviosuly I have no other choice but to go through dynaaccess to get the data from an external application, if there was another option,  i would use it

Comment: it was not meant to be sarcastic: in the question you refer to DynaAccess as an odbc driver so i suppose you can just drop it and use the default stock sql driver. if it is not that way please explain what is DynaAccess: a search on the net popped out nothing in topic with the question.